# JavaScript: Combining functions and scripts and buttons

Tags: javascript, function, button

I am going through the SAMS Learn JavaScript in 24 hours book. The end of lesson three has an extra exercise to combine a Celsius to Fahrenheit from Lesson 2, with functions and buttons from Lesson 3. I was able to successfully complete the Try It exercises in Lessons 2 and 3...

**LESSON 2**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Fahrenheit From Celsius</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
    var cTemp = 100; // temperature in Celsius
    var hTemp = ((cTemp * 9) /5 ) + 32;
    document.write("Temperature in Celsius: " + cTemp + " degrees<br/>");
    document.write("Temperature in Fahrenheit: " + hTemp + " degrees");
</script>
```

**LESSON 3**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Calling Functions</title>
<script>
    function buttonReport(buttonId, buttonName, buttonValue) {
        var userMessage1 = "Button id: " + buttonId + "\n";
        var userMessage2 = "Button name: " + buttonName + "\n";
        var userMessage3 = "Button value: " + buttonValue;
        alert(userMessage1 + userMessage2 + userMessage3);
    }
</script>
```

But I am stuck combining the two.

**EXERCISE TO COMBINE THE TWO:**

Write a function to take a temperature value in Celsius as an argument and return the equivalent temperature in Fahrenheit, basing it on the code from Lesson 2.

Test your function in an HTML page having three buttons that, when clicked, pass values of 10, 20, and 30 degrees Celsius, respectively, to the function.

**HERE'S WHAT I HAVE...(minus the headers, titles and HTML tags)**

```
    function temp(10, 20, 30) {
        var hTemp1 = ((temp * 9) /5 ) + 32;
        var hTemp2 = ((temp * 9) /5 ) + 32;
        var hTemp3 = ((temp * 9) /5 ) + 32;
        alert(hTemp1, hTemp2, hTemp3);
    }
</script>

</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="10 X Celsius" onclick = hTemp1>
<input type="button" value="20 X Celsius" onclick = hTemp2>
<input type="button" value="30 X Celsius" onclick = hTemp3>
```

Can you please help me?

Comment: `<input ... onclick = "temp(10)">`, etc. `function temp(temp) { ... }`. Probably not a good idea to have a parameter name that is the same as the function it's in.

Comment: try approaching the exercise in small steps, like with just one button and then try to complete the challenge, there are a lot of mistakes on your code so keep studying!

Answer (score 0):

There's definitely better ways to do this. But here's a solution for the purpose of this lesson. I tried not to change too much of your code. Check out the snippet below.

```js
function toF(cTmp) {
  return cTmp * 9 / 5 + 32
}

function alertF(tmp) {
  alert(toF(tmp))
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="10" onclick="alertF(10)">
<input type="button" value="20" onclick="alertF(20)">
<input type="button" value="30" onclick="alertF(30)">
```

Comment: Thank you! That did the trick. I will mess around with it so make sure I understand it before moving on to the next lesson.

Comment: @BabetteRaymond Awesome, I’m glad. If my answer solved ur problem, would u mind accepting and/or upvoting it?